# recommendations for a large book with many images

Tags: include, books

I 'm writing a book with many pages (until now are 200, expected 600) and with many `tikz`-images.

I split the book with `\include` and `\includeonly` commands for compiling speed reasons and everything is OK with every separate chapter.

The problem arises when I want to see all the book, so I delete `\includeonly` command (e.g. `%\includeonly`). At that time the document failed to compiled and I get [this](https://pastebin.com/CEnnbm3z) error message ([here](https://pastebin.com/h3XzUQXv) is the `log`-file).

1. I believe that the problem is because the book is too large and with many images. Am I right?
2. Can I solve this problem? Sometimes it is really important to me to see whole the book.
3. If I can't solve it, does it mean that I will not face any problems in the future with separate chapters? As I said, I 'm in 200 page and I have 400 more to write. Is it possible this problem to create problem in compiling each new chapter in the future (e.g. in 500 page)?
4. Is there something I should do with large documents, except `\include` and `\includeonly` commands?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't read the links (secure connection failed)... please paste the relevant parts here. But I suspect the length is not a problem. `TikZ` manual is typeset in LaTeX in pretty one go, and it's huge.

Comment: @Rmano , are you sure that you can't open the links? I opened them from different devises for sure. The text is too big for paste it here. Only this I can: `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
\pgfsyssoftpath@thepath ...vetosupportatoken \ETC.`

Comment: you ran out of main mem. Normally memory is cleared after each page is output, so if you can run the individual chapters with `\includeonly` you would expect that normally you can run the whole document. However that is not always the case but without seeing any code it is hard to say. You could look at tikz externalize feature which allows you to do each tikz as a separate run and the final run just includes the individual pdfs of each typeset tikz picture

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , thanks for your answer! I understand that you need the code, but I couldn't make a mwe, because each chapter is OK. I 'll try that you are saying with `tikz`.